# How to skip a page scrape when table is missing in R

Tags: r, web-scraping, purrr, rvest

I'm building a scrape that pulls the name of a player and the years he played for thousands of different players. I have built an otherwise successful function to do this but unfortunately in some instances the table with the other half of data I need (years played) does not exist. For these instances, I'd like to add a way to tell the scrape to bypass these instances. Here is the code:

(note: the object "url_final" is the list of active webpage URLs of which there are many)

```
library(rvest)
library(curl)
library(tidyverse)
library(httr)
df <- map_dfr(.x = url_final,
                .f = function(x){Sys.sleep(.3); cat(1); 

 fyr <- read_html(curl(x, handle = curl::new_handle("useragent" = "Mozilla/5.0"))) %>% 
  html_table() %>%
  .[[1]] 

 fyr <- fyr %>%
  select(1) %>%
  mutate(name = str_extract(string = x, pattern = "(?<=cbb/players/).*?(?=-\\d\\.html)"))

                })
```

Here is an example of an active page in which you can recreate the scrape by replacing "url_final" as the .x call in map_dfr with:

```
https://www.sports-reference.com/cbb/players/karl-aaker-1.html
```

Here is an example of one of the instances in which there is no table and thus returns an error breaking the loop of the scrape.

```
https://www.sports-reference.com/cbb/players/karl-aaker-1.html
```

Comment: Put your function in `purrr::safely()`. Side note: it looks like your example links are exactly the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about adding try-Catch which will ignore any errors?

```
library(tidyverse)
library(rvest)

df <- map_dfr(.x = url_final,
              .f = function(x){Sys.sleep(.3); cat(1); 
                 tryCatch({
                 fyr <- read_html(curl::curl(x, 
                      handle = curl::new_handle("useragent" = "Mozilla/5.0"))) %>%
                      html_table() %>% .[[1]] 

               fyr <- fyr %>%
                       select(1) %>%
                       mutate(name = str_extract(string = x, 
                         pattern = "(?<=cbb/players/).*?(?=-\\d\\.html)"))
               }, error = function(e) message('Skipping url', x))
            })
```

Comment: thank you Ronak! I figured there was a bypass solution - just didn't know what it was. Learning everyday!